# Play/Pause Jquery toggle using actions in Ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am building an audio player/playlist in Ember using the Soundmanager2 player.

I am using the following code for the play/pause actions, which trigger the song to play and pause.

The problem I am running into is that the song will play, but the pause does not work. I assume it is because the variable mySound in the pause action is technically a different song than the mySound in the play action.

Here is my code:

```
actions: {

  play: function(){
        var track_id = this.id;
        var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
          id: track_id,
          url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + track_id + '/stream?client_id=d61f17a08f86bfb1dea28539908bc9bf',
          autoplay: false,
          whileplaying: function() {
                $('#positionBar').css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%'); 
            },
         });

         this.set("isPlaying", true);
         soundManager.stopAll();
         mySound.play();  
  },

  pause: function(){
        var track_id = this.id;
        var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
          id: track_id,
          url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + track_id + '/stream?client_id=d61f17a08f86bfb1dea28539908bc9bf',
          autoplay: false,
          whileplaying: function() {
                $('#positionBar').css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%'); 
            },
         });
         this.set("isPlaying", false);
         mySound.pause();
  },

 }
```

Any help will be helpful. I am new to Ember but so perhaps my method of doing this can be done a different, more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of the `mySound` property and use it in the pause method.

```
actions: {

  play: function(){
        var track_id = this.id;
        var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
          id: track_id,
          url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + track_id + '/stream?client_id=d61f17a08f86bfb1dea28539908bc9bf',
          autoplay: false,
          whileplaying: function() {
                $('#positionBar').css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%'); 
            },
         });

         this.set("isPlaying", true);
         this.set('mySound', mySound);
         soundManager.stopAll();
         mySound.play();  
  },

  pause: function(){
        var mySound = this.get('mySound');
        this.set("isPlaying", false); 
        if(mySound && mySound.pause){
           mySound.pause(); 
        }
  },

}
```